# How to inject specific Doctrine Entity Manager in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Working on several projects which use the same database, we made a Symfony2 Bundle to map all common functions.

Now the issue is that we have a second database, and we need the same kind of service, just as the first one.

<kbd>**config.yml**</kbd>

```
doctrine:
  dbal:
    default_connection: main
    connections:
      main:
        /* ... */
      sub:
        /* ... */

  orm:
      default_entity_manager:   main
      entity_managers:
          main:
              connection:       main
              mappings:
                  AcmeMainBundle: ~
          sub:
              connection:       sub
              mappings:
                  AcmeSubBundle: ~
      auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
```

<kbd>**@AcmeMainBundle > services.yml**</kbd>

```
services:
    mainmanager:
      class: Acme\MainBundle\MainManager
      arguments: [ @doctrine.orm.entity_manager ]
```

<kbd>**Acme\MainBundle\MainManager**</kbd>

```
class MainManager
{
    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $em->getRepository('AcmeMainBundle:Foo');
    }
}
```

This set works fine, I get all expected results since `default_entity_manager` is set to `main` which is the right EntityManager.

But now here's the issue.

<kbd>**@AcmeSubBundle > services.yml**</kbd>

```
submanager:
  class: Acme\SubBundle\SubManager
  arguments: [ @doctrine.orm.entity_manager ]
```

<kbd>**Acme\SubBundle\SubManager**</kbd>

```
class SubManager
{
    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $em->getRepository('AcmeSubBundle:Bar'); // Throws exception
    }
}
```

> Unknown entity namespace alias AcmeSubBundle

Since `EntityManager` goes into `main` by default.

My question is, is there a *"clean"* way to inject a specific entity manager as argument in **services.yml** ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Answer at 18/02/13

Here is a way to pass a specific entity manager from `services.yml`
Doctrine generates a new service name relative to their names.

Example:

```
@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager
```

In this case, it generates 2 others entity manager

```
@doctrine.orm.main_entity_manager
@doctrine.orm.sub_entity_manager
```

The argument passed is a `Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager` object

In my case:

<kbd>**services.yml**</kbd>

```
submanager:
    arguments: [ @doctrine.orm.sub_entity_manager ]
```

---

> Update 22/08/13

An alternative to this would be to directly give the repository instead of the manager.

To do such, you must create a service which will hold the repository.

<kbd>**services.yml**</kbd>

```
services:
    acme.foo_repository:
        class: Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectRepository
        factory_service: doctrine.orm.main_entity_manager
        factory_method:  getRepository
        arguments:
            - "AcmeMainBundle:Foo"
```

We let doctrine generate the given repository.
Then we can inject it in another service

```
services:
    mainmanager:
        class: Acme\MainBundle\MainManager
        arguments:
            - @acme.foo_repository
```