# What is the best way to inject EventDispatcher in EntityRepository?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I would like to know what is the best practice for EventDispatcher injection in EntityRepository class.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First, using `global` is a [very bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5166527/1607098). I strongly advise you not to do this.
Second, Injecting services into a repository doesn't seem like a good idea. It will often break laws like the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

I'd create a manager that will wrap the methods of your repository, and  will trigger the events you need. See [how to inject repository to a service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13014429/1607098) for further information.

<kbd>**services.yml**</kbd>

```
services:
    my_manager:
        class: Acme\FooBundle\MyManager
        arguments:
            - @acme_foo.repository
            - @event_dispatcher

    acme_foo.repository:
        class: Acme\FooBundle\Repository\FooRepository
        factory_service: doctrine.orm.entity_manager
        factory_method: getRepository
        arguments:
            - "AcmeFooBundle:Foo"
```

<kbd>**Acme\FooBundle\MyManager**</kbd>

```
use Acme\FooBundle\Repository\FooRepository;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface;

class MyManager
{
    protected $repository;
    protected $dispatcher;

    public function __construct(FooRepository $repository, EventDispatcherInterface $dispatcher)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
        $this->dispatcher = $dispatcher;
    }

    public function findFooEntities(array $options = array())
    {
        $event = new PreFindEvent;
        $event->setOptions($options);

        $this->dispatcher->dispatch('find_foo.pre_find', $event);

        $results = $this->repository->findFooEntities($event->getOptions());

        $event = new PostFindEvent;
        $event->setResults($results);

        $this->dispatcher->dispatch('find_foo.post_find', $event);

        return $event->getResults();
    }
}
```

Then you can use it in your controller, just like a service.

```
$this->get('my_manager')->findFooEntities($options);
```

---

However, if you *really* need to inject the event dispatcher into your entity, you can do this

<kbd>**services.yml**</kbd>

```
services:
    acme_foo.repository:
        class: Acme\FooBundle\Repository\FooRepository
        factory_service: doctrine.orm.entity_manager
        factory_method: getRepository
        arguments:
            - "AcmeFooBundle:Foo"
        calls:
            - [ "setEventDispatcher", [ @event_dispatcher ] ]
```

Then you just have to add the `setEventDispatcher` method to your repository.

<kbd>**Acme\FooBundle\Repository\FooRepository**</kbd>

```
class FooRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    protected $dispatcher;

    public function setEventDispatcher(EventDispatcherInterface $dispatcher)
    {
        $this->dispatcher = $dispatcher;
    }

    public function findFooEntities(array $options = array())
    {
        $dispatcher = $this->dispatcher;

        // ...
    }
}
```

Just make sure you call the service and not the repository when using it in the controller.

**DO**

```
$this->get('acme_foo.repository')->findFooEntities();
```

**DON'T**

```
$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('AcmeFooBundle:Foo')->findFooEntities();
```

Comment: I cam here having the same problem, and your answer makes sense. However, now the Manager has 2 responsibilities, proxying the repository and raising the events. This is a very "pedantic" question, but where do you stop refactoring to get the SRP?

Comment: @JorgeeFG IMO, you can refactor it once again by having an `OptionsResolver::resolve($options)` and `ResultHandler::handle($results)` (which will both call an event) given in your Manager. The manager will then act as a simple Facade which will connect all three components. However, I really feel like adding these two interfaces would start to get overkill since there's hardly any improvement/changes you would expect by changing their behaviour since most of them can be done in event handlers.